# How to avoid top margin of an element on new pages in AntennaHouse?

Tags: xsl-fo, css-paged-media, print-css, antenna-house

I'm doing print layouts with HTML and CSS with AntennaHouse renderer.

A box in my content should have a top margin of 20pt. Easy:

```
margin-top: 20pt;
```

But the top margin should only be applied when the element doesn't stand at the beginning of a new page (when no page break is exactly before the element).

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

*XSL-FO solutions are welcome as well, as AntennaHouse has equivalent functions for FO and CSS rendering...*

Answer (score 1):

Antenna House provides also some XSL / CSS extensions (additional properties or values).
If you look at this documentation, http://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf60/docs/ahf-ext.html#IDASJ5GB, you will find the **-ah-margin-break** properties that may answer your requirements.

*Please note this is an non-standard feature (regarding XSL-FO and CSS specifications), available only in Antenna House Formatter.*

Answer (score 1):

Try `-ah-margin-break` (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.margin-break).

`-ah-margin-break: discard` will discard "the margin on the before side of the block placed at the start of the document or right after the forced page/column break."  I am not sure whether 'forced' covers a column/page break that was caused because the previous column/page was full.